# Could we see a changelog of deployments?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deployment

I know there's a SVN Revision Id at the bottom of every page, but I think it'd be nice if we could see a couple short sentences about what went into the deployment.  Not changelogs in the commits, but a little blurb like "*fixed bug with username not showing on tags/users page; added links in users profile page to other family sites*" would be handy to know what to look for.

**Edit**: Another argument for this.  At some point, careers silently changed from showing *all* of your SO accounts to letting you pick the ones you wanted.  Which is nice, great feature.  Except it hid all the accounts except SO.  So for an undetermined period of time, I was not showing flair I would have liked to show.  Obviously this isn't the end of the world, but it's example of how a changelog benefits the community.

Comment: @Koper please don't bump questions that way. If you really do have something to add/fix, do it. Otherwise, leave things as they are.

Comment: @random: The [Recent feature changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) don't really justify a [meta-tag:status-completed], do they?

Comment: The Recent changes lists recent changes and updates that affects the users with notes on where/when they were changed recently. That sounds like a completed request. @hen

Comment: @random: Often that list is updates only days later, when people have discovered the new features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recent feature changes highlights most changes / features implemented

- [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 10):

First you'd have to convince Jeff that using a bug tracking system is actually a good idea...  Good luck :P

Comment: You also have to convince Joel... :-)

Comment: I convinced both. The Feng Shui guy deep six'd the plans, a bug system would cause too much stress.

Answer (score 5):

I have a mild/manic version number fetish and I have to resist looking at the number and trying to figure out what has change (by looking at UV / blog / codinghorror twitter)

So releasing this (or a version history) could prevent me going insane.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub does something very similar thing - they simply show all commit messages (without showing diff's or anything like that)

http://github.com/changelog

Comment: Commit... messages?! :)

Comment: Yep. I was slightly surprised when they started doing it, but it makes sense. It's actually quite interesting, for example, 10 days ago there was a comment "ToS updates" which otherwise would be very difficult to know about

Comment: this makes more sense for them because their entire site is a giant source code repo. That's not really what we do here..

Answer (score 1):

```
jeff@host# hg commit -m "Muhahaah!"
```

... completely change what I just did

```
jeff@host# hg commit -m "Soon the rebellion will be crushed and young Torvalds will be one of US! ^#^&*$, wait, I hate git"
```

... completely change what I just did

```
jeff@host# su rms@gnu.org

rms@host: hg commit -m "Now you have no #&$*(& idea WHAT to think or do!"
```

Enuff said. `Status: bydesign.` Need proof? Go figure out what to do in order to get the `Generalist` badge.

PS: Don't tell Jeff that you figured out how the search worked. And here you thought [they actually used subversion](http://www.fogcreek.com/Kiln/).