# Why isn't there a change list?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, revisions-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we see a changelog of deployments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/547/could-we-see-a-changelog-of-deployments)

Why isn't there an official change list for all of the changes that are made to StackExchange and the Trilogy Sites? I think this would help to prevent many of the questions that arrive here about how users were once able to do something and now they can't. A change list would solve these problems and also it could include a list of the planned and scheduled changes such as the great rep-recalc.

Is there some reason that this does not already exist? Can The Team be so kind to tell us whenever they remove or add a feature?

Comment: I edited to fix various spelling/grammar errors. It's 'there' not 'their'

Comment: unless there's no they're their.  er, their they're.  er, ... something.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/547/could-we-see-a-changelog-of-deployments