# Start separate blog for maintenance info and new trilogy features

Tags: feature-request, blog, notifications

Merging `blog.stackexchange.com` and `blog.stackoverflow.com` was certainly a good idea. However, this has had the side effect that a lot of content is added at a faster rate. Much of that content is very broadly dealing with "company news" like new staff, related projects, the API, the progress of Area 51, Kittehs, and such.

While that is perfectly suitable for the company's official weblog and makes for fine reading, for an occasional user solely interested in changes to how the site works, it has become extremely difficult to keep track of blog posts related to those. The [post about the new bounty system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/) is already preceded by five other posts has been pushed to page 2. In the "old" blog, it would stay on the front page much, much longer, and the ratio of "technical" posts to announcements felt about equal.

Maybe starting a "maintenance blog" or "status blog" that deals with outages and changes to the system would be a good idea. The way it is now, I find it difficult to tell users popping up on Meta reporting "bugs" in the bounty system to please read the blog.

Comment: Not so much a possible duplicate of [Could we see a changelog of deployments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/547/could-we-see-a-changelog-of-deployments) (Should have read better before voting to close.)

Comment: Changes to the system (but not outages) are in the unofficial change log, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47433/monthly-summary-of-whats-new/47815#47815, "Monthly Summary of What’s New"

Comment: @Peter, that is just temporary, until something else is introduced, right? It creates a lot of noise in linked questions, and it will soon hit the maximum post length...

Comment: @Arjan: yes, I agree.

Comment: @Arjan: Since that question isn't owned by you, the post could be separated into blocks of time, maybe a year or so. As long as Justin accepts the most recent answer, the latest stuff would be stickied to the top of the question. That's maybe not the ideal solution, but it is a possible solution.

Comment: @Jon, of course, but let's not make Jeff cum suis get away with it that easily! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

blog.stackoverflow.com posts

- June 17 posts
- July 14 posts
- August 15 posts

(note that this includes at least 1 mandatory cc-wiki dump post per month)

If that's "extremely difficult to keep track of", perhaps you are setting your life goals too low?

Comment: yeah, but you are thinking of the *fans*, us Meta users, who avidly and enthusiastically read everything about S[OFUE]. Somebody not interested in the blog, looking for whether something has changed recently on how SO deals with, say, accepted answers, will have to work through a *huge* wall of text.

Comment: @pekka really? a huge wall of text? not "browse the last 15 post titles on the sidebar to see if any are interesting?"

Comment: you can make smart comments all you want, but the way it stands, the blog is not a suitable instrument to keep track of new feature developments any more. Of course everything is there *in theory*, but there is no easy way to track it. What about introducing a `feature` tag for feature announcements (instead of design / community) and `status` for outages etc.? Also, a list view in the archives (instead of seeing the full posts) might be helpful.

Comment: [HA HA IN YOUR FACE](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/07/the-new-stack-exchange-blog/)

Comment: That's a long time to hold a grudge.

Comment: @Pëkka, as if 5 years didn't changed anything.

Comment: @BeatAlex YOU WILL NOT SPOIL MY TRIUMPH